# Recycle bin in lightning

Tags: recycle

Why do users have to switch from lightning to classic to get access to the Recycle bin. Is the Recycle bin not supported in lightning?

Comment: This is a gap in LEX that will likely be addressed in the future.

Comment: Idea is already raised: [Lightning Experience - Recycle Bin](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DsAuAAK)

Comment: You can also try this app on AppExchange: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJrJuUAL

Answer (score 4):

We are looking for this change but found some workaround to fix this. Because it is highly required for my client.

Workaround: Redirect to salesforce classic recycle bin on click of custom tab.

**Steps 1.** Created a visualforce page. VF Page Name: RecycleBin

```
<apex:page controller="RecycleBin" action="{!redirect}">
</apex:page>
```

**Step 2:** Created a controller

```
public with sharing class RecycleBin {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/search/UndeletePage');
        return pg;
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** Created a custom visualforce tab.
click on Setup-->Tabs-->scroll down to visualforce tab-->New-->select RecycleBin visualforce page name. and finish the tab setup for respective app.